# Probability bounds on size of smaller partition in randomized quicksort

Tags: algorithms, sorting, probability-theory, probabilistic-algorithms, quicksort

Let $0 < a < 0.5$ be some constant. We have an $n$-element array as input. Randomized quicksort chooses one element from array uniformly at random as a pivot and partitions. With probability $1-2a$ the smallest section be greater than $an$.
How we can Calculate this probability?
after 72 hours try i reach to following that means valid area is (1-a)n-an=n(1-2a). by dividing n(1-2a)/ n we get 1-2a.
[image]

Comment: "the smallest section is smaller than `an`", can you explain that?

Comment: @Nehorai The smaller section of the array after pivoting (either the things less than the pivot or things greater than it) contains at most $an$ elements.

Comment: @JohnatanMorian Thanks -- that makes more sense. Close vote retracted.

Comment: What's your question?  I don't see a question in this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose for simplicity that all elements are distinct, and that after sorting, these elements are $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. A random pivot has the same distribution as $x_i$ for $i$ chosen uniformly at random from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. The size of the smaller partition is $\min(i-1,n-i)$. If $I$ is the set of indices $i$ such that $\min(i-1,n-i) \geq an$, then the probability you are looking for is $|I|/n$ (by the definition of uniform probability). I'll let you complete the calculation.

Comment: No, now it's time for you to think hard until you solve this.

Comment: Make sure that you understand what probability means. The probability that the random index $i$ lies in some set $I \subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}$ is $|I|/n$. In your case $I$ is the set of indices for which the smaller partition is larger than $an$. So you just have to calculate the size of $I$. If you don't solve such problems yourself you'll never get better.

Comment: Perhaps you should take this opportunity to learn some basic probability. You can't expect to answer probability questions without knowing basic probability theory. This will only get worse as the course proceeds.

Comment: No, I'm afraid you'll have to sweat it.

Comment: What you added to your question is certainly the idea, but you also need to add a proof in English explaining what you have done.

Comment: You need the proof to look like in the textbook. Explain all the steps, not only the final calculation. At this point it's best to consult a local TA.

Comment: No. Please consult a local TA. Stackexchange cannot function as a private tutor.